# Rudin chapter 3 Functional Analysis problem 3

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose 
X is  a real 
vector 
space 
(without 
topology). 
Call 
a point 
$x_o\in
A\subset
X$ an 
internal 
point 
of 
$A$ 
if 
$A-x_o$
is 
an absorbing 
set.

(a) Suppose 
$A $
and 
$B $
are disjoint 
convex 
sets 
in $ X$, 
and 
$A$
has an
internal 
point. 
Prove 
that  there  is 
a  nonconstant 
linear 
functional 
$f$ 
on 
$X $
such 
that 
$f(A)\cap
f(B)$  contains 
at 
most 
one 
point.

(b) 
Show 
(with 
$X= 
\mathbf R^2$, 
for 
example) 
that 
it may 
not 
be 
possible 
to 
have $f(A)$ and $
f(B)$ 
disjoint, 
under 
the 
hypotheses 
of 
(a).

i had already proved part (a) but i am not able to understand what part(b) want to ask.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For part (b), consider the two subsets of $\mathbb R^2$,
$$ A = \{ y > 0 \} \cup \{ x < 0,\, y \geq 0 \}$$
and
$$ B = \{ (0,0) \}\,. $$
Then any line in $\mathbb R^2$ that passes through the origin will intersect both $A$ and $B$, meaning that it is not possible to separate them with a linear functional.

To be precise, if $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is any linear functional, then $\ker f$ is a line through the origin. Since $\ker f$ intersects both $A$ and $B$, we have $0 \in f(A) \cap f(B)$. Thus $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ will never be disjoint.

Comment: the reasoning for it is may be as any linear functional $f: R^2\rightarrow R$ will have a non trivial kernel for sure and for $\ker f$ to be a line passing from the origin is due to linearity of the map. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.